# Android Launch Sceneform Activity from Camera Button

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

I am creating an app with Sceneform and when I press the camera button I want the user to be navigated to the ArFragment which I have included in another activity. The PoiPaintingARCamera Activity works flawlessly if implemented by itself in a new activity.
[Sample Photo of the Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDf4Q.png)

This is the code that I use in the PoiPainting Activity

```
btnCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(PoiPainting.this, PoiPaintingArCamera.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Code for the PoiPaintingARActivity

```
public class PoiPaintingArCamera extends AppCompatActivity {

private ExternalTexture texture;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private ArFragment arFragment;
private Scene scene;
private ModelRenderable renderable;
private boolean isImageDetected = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_poi_painting_ar_camera);

    texture = new ExternalTexture();

    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.video);
    mediaPlayer.setSurface(texture.getSurface());
    mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);

    ModelRenderable
            .builder()
            .setSource(this, Uri.parse("video_screen.sfb"))
            .build()
            .thenAccept(modelRenderable -> {
                modelRenderable.getMaterial().setExternalTexture("videoTexture",
                        texture);
                modelRenderable.getMaterial().setFloat4("keyColor",
                        new Color(0.01843f, 1f, 0.098f));

                renderable = modelRenderable;
            });

    arFragment = (com.stratos.syrostownhall.CustomArFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.arFragment);

    if (arFragment != null) {
        scene = arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene();
    }

    scene.addOnUpdateListener(this::onUpdate);

}

private void onUpdate(FrameTime frameTime) {

    if (isImageDetected)
        return;

    Frame frame = arFragment.getArSceneView().getArFrame();

    Collection<AugmentedImage> augmentedImages =
            frame != null ? frame.getUpdatedTrackables(AugmentedImage.class) : null;


    for (AugmentedImage painting : Objects.requireNonNull(augmentedImages)) {
        if (painting.getTrackingState() == TrackingState.TRACKING) {

            if (painting.getName().equals("painting")) {

                isImageDetected = true;

                playVideo(painting.createAnchor(painting.getCenterPose()), painting.getExtentX(),
                        painting.getExtentZ());

                break;
            }

        }
    }

}

private void playVideo(Anchor anchor, float extentX, float extentZ) {

    mediaPlayer.start();

    AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);

    texture.getSurfaceTexture().setOnFrameAvailableListener(surfaceTexture -> {
        anchorNode.setRenderable(renderable);
        texture.getSurfaceTexture().setOnFrameAvailableListener(null);
    });

    anchorNode.setWorldScale(new Vector3(extentX, 1f, extentZ));

    scene.addChild(anchorNode);

}
```

The app crashes when I press the camera button giving me the following message.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.stratos.syrostownhall, PID: 30431
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.stratos.syrostownhall/com.stratos.syrostownhall.PoiPaintingArCamera}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment cannot be cast to com.stratos.syrostownhall.CustomArFragment
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3410)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2017)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7397)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment cannot be cast to com.stratos.syrostownhall.CustomArFragment
    at com.stratos.syrostownhall.PoiPaintingArCamera.onCreate(PoiPaintingArCamera.java:59)
```

Is there any way I can make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lied to the `anroid:name` of the sceneform CustomArFragment class. Changing the name to the android directory fixed the problem.